# My getter and setters aren't working? Returning nullobjectreference?

Tags: java, android, methods, static, getter-setter

new to Java/Android development here. Recently I have been using static variables to access user input from the main activity, in another class. I was told to change this to getter/setter methods as using static variables isn't good code in java (so I heard?). So therefore I made these methods and accessed them in other classes by creating an instance of the activity (MainActivity in this case) and then calling the method using a constructor. Anyway here is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//declare variables
EditText name;
EditText data;
EditText wlan;
EditText utility;
Button addservice;
ListView lv;
ListView lv2;
ListView lv3;
ListView lv4;
public ArrayList<String> servicenames;
public ArrayList<String> dimensions;
public ArrayList<Double> costDATA;
public ArrayList<Double> costWLAN;
public ArrayList<Double> costUTILITY;
ArrayAdapter<String> namesAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<Double> dataAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<Double> wlanAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<Double> utilityAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //map the components to the variables
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.servicename);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);
    wlan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wlan);
    utility = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.utility);
    addservice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addservice);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv2);
    lv3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv3);
    lv4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv4);

    //create arraylists for each component
    servicenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    dimensions = new ArrayList<String>();
    costDATA = new ArrayList<Double>();
    costWLAN = new ArrayList<Double>();
    costUTILITY = new ArrayList<Double>();

    //create adapters to pass on the arraylist
    namesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, servicenames);
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costDATA);
    wlanAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costWLAN);
    utilityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costUTILITY);

    //display each arraylist in the listviews
    lv.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
    lv2.setAdapter(wlanAdapter);
    lv3.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    lv4.setAdapter(utilityAdapter);
    namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    wlanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    utilityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dimensions.add("DATA");
    dimensions.add("WLAN");
    onClickBtn();
}

public void onClickBtn() { //when user clicks button, the user input is added to the listview, and cleared for the next service

    addservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String namesOfService = name.getText().toString(); //user input for service names
            String costOfData = data.getText().toString(); //user input for data costs
            String costOfWLAN = wlan.getText().toString(); //user input for wlan costs
            String costOfUtility = utility.getText().toString(); //user input for utility costs
            Double doubleWLAN = Double.parseDouble(costOfWLAN); //convert user input into double
            Double doubleData = Double.parseDouble(costOfData);
            Double doubleUtility = Double.parseDouble(costOfUtility);
            costDATA.add(doubleData); //add the double costs to each resource arraylist
            costWLAN.add(doubleWLAN);
            costUTILITY.add(doubleUtility);
            servicenames.add(namesOfService);
            dimensions.add(namesOfService);
            int dimensionSize = dimensions.size();
            namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            wlanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            utilityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            name.setText(""); //empty the edit text fields when button is clicked
            wlan.setText("");
            data.setText("");
            utility.setText("");

        }
    });
}

public void nextButton(View view) //next button, onto the next activity
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ParticleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public int getDimensions(){

    return dimensions.size();

}

public ArrayList<String> getElements(){ return servicenames;}

public ArrayList<Double> getCostDATA(){;return costDATA;}

public ArrayList<Double> getCostWLAN(){return costUTILITY;}

public ArrayList<Double> getCostUTILITY(){return costUTILITY;}
}
```

I need to access the arraylists costData,costUtilities,costWlan and dimensions in other classes. Here is my other class...

```
public class CustomUseCase extends Test {

MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
ParticleActivity particleActivity = new ParticleActivity();
public int numberOfDimensions = mainActivity.getDimensions();
private ArrayList<Double> costData = mainActivity.getCostDATA(); //costs that the user enters for each resource
private ArrayList<Double> costWlan = mainActivity.getCostWLAN();
private ArrayList<Double> costUtilities = mainActivity.getCostUTILITY();
private double batteryCost = particleActivity.getBatteryCost();
private int maxIter;
private int noParticles;
```

What am I doing wrong here? An explanation into why I got it wrong would be a bonus! Kind regards.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot i know that. However in my mainactivity, you can see that when the user enters a cost, it is added to each arraylist. So when my UI starts, I enter these costs but then my UI doesn't execute what I need it to because it says the array its trying to access is empty

Comment: Sidenote: "good" can be relative. When it comes to performance, the Android guidelines advise against internal getters / setters and even have a point about static final for constants: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Answer (score 0):

You have no constructor for your MainActivity class. This means that all your variables are defined, but none of them are actually initialized when you call

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

The `new` keyword being important here. Note that this doesn't necessarily mean your app wont work, depending on it's setup, but the test case definitely wont.

I think in your case you need to add:

```
public MainActivity(){
  onCreate(savedInstance); //Bundle savedInstance
}
```

Comment: ahh that makes sense thank you. Where do I insert this? In the mainactivity? I just tried to add this in the mA but i get (cannot resolve method onCreate())?

Comment: That error is because you need to pass a `Bundle` as a parameter to the `onCreate()` method. I don't know where you'd get this from. I forgot to mention that in my answer; updated it there.

Comment: Is the constructor and onCreate method part of the same class?

Comment: Which constructor? Do you mean where I make an instance of MainActivity? If so, then no

Comment: The constructor should be a part of the MainActivity class, the same place `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` is overridden.